# How do I (correctly) manage/update search domains with systemd?

Tags: systemd-networkd, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I have a system (running Ubuntu 20.04) with multiple network interfaces and I realized that the search domains (I'm looking at `/etc/resolv.conf`, which I know is just a symlink to a `systemd-resolved` managed file) are getting added automatically as soon as I plug in a new cable. That's nice!

Unfortunately, when doing the reverse (i.e., disconnecting a cable), the search domain entries are left untouched, creating all sorts of unwanted side-effects.

Example:

- Plug cable into `eno1`:

  ```
  #$> cat /etc/resolv.conf
  nameserver 127.0.0.53
  options edns0
  search mydomain.com
  #$>
  ```
- Plug cable into `eno2`:

  ```
  #$> cat /etc/resolv.conf
  nameserver 127.0.0.53
  options edns0
  search mydomain.com additionaldomain.com
  #$>
  ```
- *Unplug* cable out of `eno2`:

  ```
  #$> cat /etc/resolv.conf
  nameserver 127.0.0.53
  options edns0
  search mydomain.com additionaldomain.com
  #$>
  ```

As far as I understand, I *could* reboot the system or edit the appropriate files manually; but as soon as I plug a cable back in, I'm back to square one.

What program manages the search domain entries in resolv.conf, and how do I "force" an update of those entries?